# Cypher commands not being recognised

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using Neo4j for a project, when I try to run `SHOW DATABASES`, I get this error:

```
Invalid input 'H': expected 't/T', 'e/E' or 'n/N' (line 1, column 2 (offset: 1))

"SHOW DATABASES"
```

I'm running Neo4j Browser version: 4.0.3.

Why is this function not recognized? It's referenced multiple times in the docs. I have no issues running other queries with different commands, but this is not recognized.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHOW DATABASES command is against the system database. Please see the following excerpt from https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/4.0/monitoring/individual-db-states/

13.7.1. Listing Databases
First ensure that you are executing queries against the system database, either by running the command :use system (if using the Cypher shell or Neo4j Browser) or by creating a session against the system database using a Neo4j driver. Subsequently, run the SHOW DATABASES command.

Syntax:

SHOW DATABASES